# localhost versus Remote Server Errors

Tags: php

After uploading to remote server I noticed so many errors that didn't show on localhost.

On localhost I have `display_errors` to ON

How can implement a more strict environment on my localhost so that I can see all the errors.

Kind of emulating the remote server environment.

Answer (score 0):

you have to check your error reporting level in `php.ini`

You can look for the `error_reporting` instruction,I believe the default should be like this

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
```

Also for your reference the php [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) about those instructions, on your localhost I would advice to have the error_reporting being `E_ALL` or `E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE`.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the reporting level using:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
```

To decide which level you need to use, check documentation (I'd recommend the above for development):

[List of levels](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php)

[Error reporting function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Comment: Is it possible that you are getting those errors due to your application doesnt work in your remote server instead of because the errors are hidden?

Comment: error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT); error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);------did not work

Comment: I meant that maybe you have a different PHP version, or something is missing in your remote server, and thats the reason why you are getting those errors in the remote, but you don't get them in your localhost.

Comment: Good point. localhost is 5.3.0 and remote host is 5.2.15-----My apps work well on my localhost but gives errors on remote server...An example is "only variables should be passed by reference error"